# PHP Storm rewrite for internal webserver

Tags: debugging, phpstorm

I'm setting up a new [slim framework](http://www.slimframework.com/) project and I want to debug it using PHP Storms zero configuration debugging. I followed [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm) guide and I'm able to get a debug connection and inspect my variabes. So far, so good.

At the moment I'm accessing my projets files via the following URL:

`http://localhost:3337/myProjectName/`

The problem I'm encountering now is that I'm required to set the server's document root to /myProjectName/public/ as I'm using [this slim skeleton](https://github.com/codeguy/Slim-Skeleton). Is it possible to tell the build-in server to use this path as root? If not, can anyone tell me how to setup remote debugging using an apache server in my xampp environment. I tried to follow the docs but can't get the deployment to work.

Thanks!

Comment: **1)** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE **2)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/ **3)** http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/webinar-recording-deployment-with-phpstorm/

Comment: *"The problem I'm encountering now is that I'm required to set the server's document root to /myProjectName/public/"* Cannot say much about `public` .. but you can make it using this URL: `http://myProjectName:3337/` instead of `http://localhost:3337/myProjectName/` -- just edit your `hosts` file (or local DNS server, if preferred and have one) and point it to your computer's IP.

Comment: As for `public` while using built-in server -- try marking it as `Resource Root` -- accordingly to devs it should help here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14350#comment=27-860905

Comment: Oh, I should have been able to discover this myself. Make it an answer and I'll gladly accept it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of links with articles/manuals first:

1. [Installing and Configuring XAMPP with PhpStorm IDE](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Installing+and+Configuring+XAMPP+with+PhpStorm+IDE)
2. [Webinar Recording: Debugging PHP with PhpStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/)
3. [Webinar Recording: Deployment with PhpStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/webinar-recording-deployment-with-phpstorm/)

---

You can change built-in server URLs a bit: `http://myProjectName:3337/` instead of `http://localhost:3337/myProjectName/`.

For that:

- edit your hosts file (or local DNS server, if preferred and have one) and point `myProjectName` to your computer's IP
- create Deployment entry of correct type (`In Place` should do) and mark it as Default -- now IDE will use URL from there when generating URLs

As for `public` problem while using built-in server -- try marking that folder as **Resource Root** -- [accordingly to devs](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14350#comment=27-860905) it should help here: `http://myProjectName:3337/public/image.png` and `http://myProjectName:3337/image.png` will be treated the same (IDE will check for files in both locations when serving it via built-in server).